# Java NETCONF library?

Tags: java, ietf-netconf

Does anyone know if there is a Java library out there to manage configs via NETCONF?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we offer a NETCONF client library in Java called ConfM here: http://www.tail-f.com/products/confm . I'll be more than happy to provide you with more information if you are interested.

The IETF NETCONF working group maintains a somewhat updated list of NETCONF implementations here:
 http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/netconf/trac/wiki#NetconfImplementations

Comment: thanks - is it free? open source?

Comment: It is not free or open source, but I can probably make it available for evaluation free of cost if you are interested. Again, feel free to contact me directly.

If you require a formally free/open source implementations the closest I know of is a python implementation available here:
 http://code.google.com/p/ncclient/

Answer (score 1):

I am developing a library for use by Java & netconf Android.

It 's very easy to use.
Was designed to have a future use with YANG modules (RFC6020) but can be used
very well as it is.

It is able to provide a good level of abstraction.

This is the actual home page:
http://code.google.com/p/netconf4android/

Giuseppe Palmeri

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented a netconf library (it is tested with different juniper routers).

http://code.google.com/p/netconf4j/

It works fine enough. We are using it in our projects.

Comment: any plans to place the polled data into database?

Comment: Sorry, at present, I don't work in the project... you should ask some project commiter...